# How to plot this easy function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

This is very easy question, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
here is a function and I want to plot it, 
sampling rate is `1KHz` over `t=[0,1]`
function is : 
[image]
It must look like this as I saw in the paper.
[image]

here is what I have tried:

```
t=0:1:1000;
sig =exp(-(t-400).^2/2).*cos(2*pi*(t-400)/10)...
     +exp(-(t-425).^2/2).*cos(2*pi*(t-425)/15)...
     +exp(-(t-440).^2/2).*cos(2*pi*(t-440)/10);
 plot(t./1000,sig)
```

and It gives me following plot: 
[image]
This is very easy question, but I am so confused.

Comment: You may be getting the sample period (scale of t) wrong. And I think the expression you give don't match the figure: the frequency of the cosines should be higher

Comment: I have used scale of `t=0:0.001:1` as well. but it only give me a Zero line. So I thought the author might means what I have wrote @LuisMendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the function. You have something that looks like a Gaussian, for example

```
exp(-(t-400).^2/2)
```

that multiplies a cosine wave.  Unfortunately you are not evaluating your function at many points inside the Gaussian - the function is too narrow (sigma = 1). Your plot is correct; in order to see things properly, you need to have the right scale (width of the Gaussian and frequency of the cosine functions). With a little bit of fiddling, I got the following (this is update from my first answer):

```
t=linspace(0, 1000, 1000);
sig =exp(-(t-400).^2/200).*cos(2*pi*(t-400)/10)...
     +exp(-(t-425).^2/200).*cos(2*pi*(t-425)/15)...
     +exp(-(t-440).^2/200).*cos(2*pi*(t-440)/10);
 plot(t./1000,sig)
```

Which resulted in

[image]

Clearly there is a problem with the scale - once the sigma was made 10x larger (so sigma^2 is 100 times bigger) it worked as expected.

Looks to me like a typo in the original paper…

As an aside, I find that usually you want to write things out "exactly as you intend" - so if you want to use time in msec, use frequency in kHz; and remember that in the Gaussian, you have `2*sigma^2` in the denominator.

Comment: aww Thanks dude,it looks much better, But why it doesn't look exactly same, the paper is for Elsevier journal. @floris

Comment: I found the scaling that reproduces the original figure exactly. Sigma was off by 10x.